# Redirecting input and output in a shell

Tags: c, shell, stdout, stdin

Hi I've been programming a shell in c and I got stuck while trying to redirect. While redirecting the stdout in my program works the stdin doesn't.

```
void redirect(node_t* node){
    // mode 0: >$%d mode 1: < mode 2: > mode 3: >>
    int input = 0;
    if(node->redirect.mode == 2){
        input = 1; // >
    } else{
        input = 0; // <
    }
    int pid = 0;
    int *status = 0;
    char * filename = node->redirect.target; // filename
    int fd;
    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    if((pid = fork()) == 0){
        dup2(fd, input); // STDIN OR STDOUT
        close(fd);
        node_t* node2 = node->redirect.child;
        execvp(node2->command.program, node2->command.argv); // execute program
        printf("failed to execvp\n");
        exit(1);        
    } else {
        wait(status);
    }
}
```

I'm new to the `fork()` but my question is what am I doing wrong here that redirecting stdout works but stdin it writes nothing to the given file.

Comment: Since the filedescriptor is opened `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`, the child process cannot read any data from it. You would need to open it `O_RDONLY` in the case of stdin redirection.

Comment: @Ctx I've replaced the `O_WRONLY` with `O_RDONLY` but it had no effect. But why should it ready any data since I need to write the stdin into it?

Comment: Redirecting the stdin of a process usually means to give it a filedescriptor to _read_ from (this is merely a convention, technically it is of course possible to write to stdin, too).

Comment: Your last comment confuses me. You try to write in `stdin`? Could you please make a MCVE so wa can better unsderstand what you are trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use different open options depending on whether you're opening the file for input or output redirection. You can put this into your `if`.

```
int flags;
if(node->redirect.mode == 2){
    input = 1; // >
    flags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC;
} else{
    input = 0; // <
    flags = O_RDONLY;
}
int pid = 0;
int *status = 0;
char * filename = node->redirect.target; // filename
int fd;
fd = open(filename, flags, 0666);
```

Also, you need to specify the permission modes for the case where the output file is created. It's OK to specify this argument all the time, it will be ignored when `O_CREAT` isn't in the flags.

Comment: It worked thanks for your answer. This question turned out to be "how to open filedescriptors correctly".